# How to log the search history in Mac Dictionary when using the pop-up dictionary mode

Tags: applescript, dictionary

[how to log the search history in mac dictionary](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284646/how-to-log-the-search-history-in-mac-dictionary)
The answer to this post provides an AppleScript to record the words that have been looked up by actually opening the Dictionary app (using an assigned keyboard shortcut).

Is there a way to record the words that have been looked up in the pop-up dictionary mode (using the default Ctrl-Command-d shortcut)?